# Link to Outlook Inbox Folder from External Program - Is it possible?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, hyperlink, inbox

I maintain my to-do list, meeting notes, the status of projects, etc. in OneNote. In Outlook, I have folders for each project (with emails, meetings, etc.). Is there any way to insert a link in OneNote that would open outlook and view a specific inbox subfolder?

Comment: Google -> https://www.davidtan.org/create-hyperlinks-to-outlook-messages-folders-contacts-events/

Comment: Hi Hannu,I did Google, and was able to find the link you cite. However, the site offers just one sentence on how this should be able to work. I have tried their recommendations (have link direct to 'Outlook:Inbox\', as well as permutations such as '<Outlook:\Inbox>') but none seem to work. The site does not have any information about troubleshooting, or known situations/software setups where this may not work. I'd be very interested in step-by-step instructions for this.